# Get if my app is authorized to use facebook [iOS 6, FB SDK 3.2]

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, privacy

how can i know is my app is authorized by user to use Facebook?

You can enable or disable it in "Settings -> Privacy -> Facebook".
I have to get this state.

I'm using Facebook 3.2

Thank you all!

Comment: maybe this can helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473782/facebook-ios-check-if-my-facebook-app-is-allready-authorized

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the ACAccountStore to get the Facebook account(if it is available) and check if the access is granted:

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

if(accountType.accessGranted){
    //app has permissions
}else{
    //no permissions
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to reenable the app or remove it? I'm using parse with the facebook sdk. I initially denied my app and then retried to log in but kept getting a error because the app is now set to not authorized in the settings.

Comment: @mati: This is only for checking whether the access for the app in the device is granted or not? How to enable the access for the app programatically?

Comment: @Ajitthala, You should use the FB SDK in order to get FB permissions for your app. https://developers.facebook.com/ios/. It has a fallback to web/fb app authorization in case it's not iOS 6 or above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a line of code that checks, it's this one right here:

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
{

//code goes here

}
```

**NOTE**

This code will help *only* if you are using the Social Framework.