# How to implement Facebook native login for iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, oauth

What is the best practice to support Facebook logins for my app?

I’m looking at existing integration apps are having with Facebook.
Taking Pinterest for example, the app is using iOS native login even without the Facebook application installed on the device. I would like to implement such logic flow too.

Looking at:

[Get if my app is authorized to use facebook [iOS 6, FB SDK 3.2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465602/get-if-my-app-is-authorized-to-use-facebook-ios-6-fb-sdk-3-2)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/social/slcomposeviewcontroller

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accounts

It’s not clear to me how to implement a fallback process, where the app does the following:

If device login is possible, use it. If not, fallback to Facebook app login, if not fallback to Facebook Safari login.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this authentication when opening session as below.. This enum `FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent` will do as like step as below

1. Try to access Facebook account in setting app
2. if fail #1, move to fast app switch if Facebook native app installed
3. If fail in #2, it will switch to safari.

   `[FBSession.activeSession openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent
                                       completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                           FBSessionState state,
                                                           NSError *error) {
                                          //your code.
                                       }];`

Enumeration constant clearly explain about login flow, we may select any one of this as we want.

> @discussion  Facebook Login authorizes the application to act on
>   behalf of the user, using the user's  Facebook account. Usually a
>   Facebook Login will rely on an account maintained outside of  the
>   application, by the native Facebook application, the browser, or
>   perhaps the device  itself. This avoids the need for a user to enter
>   their username and password directly, and  provides the most secure
>   and lowest friction way for a user to authorize the application to 
>   interact with Facebook. If a Facebook Login is not possible, a
>   fallback Facebook Login may be  attempted, where the user is prompted
>   to enter their credentials in a web-view hosted directly  by the
>   application.
>
> The `FBSessionLoginBehavior` enum specifies whether to allow
>   fallback, disallow fallback, or  force fallback login behavior. Most
>   applications will use the default, which attempts a normal  Facebook
>   Login, and only falls back if needed. In rare cases, it may be
>   preferable to disallow  fallback Facebook Login completely, or to
>   force a fallback login.  */

```
typedef enum {
    /*! Attempt Facebook Login, ask user for credentials if necessary */
    FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithFallbackToWebView      = 0,
    /*! Attempt Facebook Login, no direct request for credentials will be made */
    FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithNoFallbackToWebView    = 1,
    /*! Only attempt WebView Login; ask user for credentials */
    FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView             = 2,
    /*! Attempt Facebook Login, prefering system account and falling back to fast app switch if necessary */
    FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent  = 3,
} FBSessionLoginBehavior;
```

**Note:** Check document to how to do app switch with FB app. then only this enum will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook SDK used to do this automatically, but stopped. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23665577/2715) for how to login to Facebook with native OS components.

Answer (score -2):

There is no need to implement login screen when you are integrating facebook with native facebook app. for this you should logged in facebook app in iOS device by simply going

Setting->facebook.

Comment: in some apps you just want to use Facebook app, if it is installed on device rather than use web login